# Moving unique_ptr inside a lambda function gives me a compiler error on C++17

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, c++17, move-semantics

Given the following hierarchy:

```
class IJobInterface
{
};

class JobAbstract : public IJobInterface
{
public:
    JobAbstract(std::string n) : name(n) {};

protected:
    std::string name;
};

class JobConcrete: public JobAbstract
{
public: 
    JobConcrete(std::string n, int i) : JobAbstract(n), index(i) {};
    void doIt();

private:
    int index;
};
```

When I need to pass `JobConcrete` as unique_ptr param inside a lambda function:

```
void doSomenthigHeavy(std::unique_ptr<JobConcrete> j)
{
    j->doIt();
}

void main()
{
    auto job = std::make_unique<JobConcrete>("name", 0);
    doSomenthigHeavy(std::move(job)); //it works

    auto t = std::thread([j = std::move(job)]
    {
        doSomenthigHeavy(std::move(j)); //it doesn't work
    });
}
```

Then I get a compiler error:
[image]

The question is: what am I missing here?
Calling `doSomenthigHeavy` from inside a lambda produces a compiler error while from outside it doesn't.

Comment: `auto t = std::thread([j = std::move(job)]() mutable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that lambda's `operator ()` is declared `const` and with the move you try to modify the unique pointer `j`.

Declare it mutable via `auto t = std::thread([j = std::move(job)]() mutable ...)` or pass the `unique_ptr` as an argument to the lambda.